# How to get the reason of 'org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement' via Try Catch and GetMessage?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I attempt to run a line in Java (with Hibernate) to save to a database. I deliberately tried saving while making an error, like saving a 10-length string to a column set with VARCHAR(5).

If I use try-catch and then use getMessage() to store into a String, then I only get "org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement". But if I use printStackTrace, I get the more detailed cause message of "value too large for column". Using getStackTrace() seems to overbloat the memory, so I want to avoid using that.

What should I use in order to get that cause mesage from the GenericJDBCException? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The java.io.NotSerializableException error is typically thrown in Spark when attempting to serialize an object that is not serializable. In your case, it looks like you are trying to convert a Spark ArrayType to a Java List, which is not a serializable operation.

To resolve this issue, you can try converting the ArrayType to a serializable format before converting it to a List. One way to do this is by converting the ArrayType to a Java array of String objects, which is serializable. You can then convert this Java array to a List if needed.

Here's an example code snippet that shows how to convert a Spark ArrayType to a Java array of String objects:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;

ArrayType arrayType = DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType);
String[] stringArray = (String[]) arrayType.sqlType().defaultSize();
```

Once you have the Java array of String objects, you can convert it to a List using the Arrays.asList() method:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
```

Note that this approach assumes that the ArrayType contains only String elements. If the ArrayType contains elements of another type, you'll need to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: You are answering the wrong question. I think you are meant to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76127994/caused-by-java-io-notserializableexception-when-converting-spark-arraytype-to not this question.